# UITapGestureRecognizer не прикрепляет действие

Tags: swift, делегаты, uitapgesturerecognizer

Я пытаюсь добавить UITapGestureRecognizer к UIImage.
Но когда я запускаю проект - ничего не происходит.

В чем может быть проблема?

Вот мой код:

Controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, APOTDViewDelegate {
    
    let av = APOTDView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        av.delegate = self
        
        addSubviews()
        setupConstraint()
    }
    
    func addSubviews() {
        // ...
    }
    
    func setupConstraint() {
        // ...
    }
    
    @objc func viewDidTapImage() {
        print("good job")
    }
    
}
```

View:

```
import UIKit

protocol APOTDViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func viewDidTapImage()
}

class APOTDView: UIView {
    
    weak var delegate: APOTDViewDelegate?
    
    var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        imageView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    @objc func imageTapped() {
        delegate?.viewDidTapImage()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Из кода не видно, добавили ли Вы av и imageView в качестве subview, выставили ли их size.

Comment: `view.addSubview(av.imageView)` и `av.imageView.topAnchor.constraint...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `var imageView: UIImageView = {` на `lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {`

Comment: Все работает! А можете обьяснить почему? Я думал lazy для памяти и что без этого все равно должно работать.

Comment: Жест тап не срабатывал, т.к. imageView еще не находился в иерархии view при простом его создании. lazy означает отложенную инициализацию, т.е. инициализация происходит только в тот момент, когда происходит обращение к объекту. Таким образом, объект imageView создается только тогда, когда Вы добавляете его в иерархию view, и, соответственно, срабатывает тап.